# List the members and find the cardinality of the sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Could anyone help me understanding this question ?

> List the members and find the cardinality of the following sets :
> $$A=\{x\mid x \text{ is a real number such that } x^4=4\}$$
> $$B=\{x\mid x = 2n - 5, x \text{ and }n \text{ are natural numbers}\}$$
> $$C=\{x\mid x \text{ is a prime number less than } 100\}$$
> $$D=\{x\mid x \text{ is the square of an integer and } x<200\}$$

For $C$ and $D$, I was able to solve it. For $A$, I'm not sure but I think it's equal to the empty set (there is no number that fit the formula).

*I found an answer that say $B=\{1, 3, 5, 7, \dots\}$ but I didn't get it!!*
Could you help me understand how to solve $B$ please!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $(\pm\sqrt2)^4=4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome.

Cardinality means just the size of the set.
How many numbers are there in the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$?

For $A$, just power both sides by $\frac{1}{4}$, is this a real number? and since $x$ is even powered, you have both positive and negative solutions.

For $B$, first you know that $n$ is a natural number, meaning $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \dots$. Just plug in $n$ into the equation of $x$, what $x$ do you get? From this $x$, which of them are *also* natural numbers?

Hope it helps,